# Mongoose persist ref not working nor updating on properties on a model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I"m using Mongoose with MongoDB,I have this code below that (1) retrieves a *client* model and (2) then associate it with a new *scope* model and save. The problem is when I persist my *scope* model, it doesn't save the association with client:

```
await connectionManager.connect();
let client = await connectionManager.getClient().findOne({'client' : 'local'});
let grant = await connectionManager.getGrant().findOne({'name' : 'Client_Credential'});
let service = await connectionManager.getService().findOne({'description' : 'Service 1'});
let ScopeModel = connectionManager.getScope();
let scope = new ScopeModel({client_id : client._id, grant_id : grant._id, service_id : service._id});
await scope.save();

console.log(await connectionManager.getClient().findOne({'client' : 'local'}).populate('scopes'));
console.log(await connectionManager.getScope().findOne({}));
```

This is what console.log line prints out:

```
 { _id: 5a0706cc26b1572d945811b4,
  name: 'Blah LTD',
  address: '',
  city: '',
  country: 'Unknown',
  telephone: '',
  owner: true,
  url: '',
  client: 'local',
  client_secret: 'secret',
  email: 'email' }


{ _id: 5a0e870a2f013725402ea5dd, __v: 0 }
```

The same more or less is shown in my *scope* collection in MongoDB after saving:

```
_id: 5a0e870a2f013725402ea5dd
__v: 0
```

Not sure what the `__v:0` represents but, anyways the schemas are shown below:

**Client Collection:**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let ClientSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    address: String,
    city: String,
    country: String,
    telephone: String,
    owner: Boolean,
    url: String
});

ClientSchema.virtual("scopes", {
    ref : 'Scope',
    localField : '_id',
    foreignField : 'client_id',
    justOne: false
});

export default ClientSchema;
```

**My Scope Collection**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ScopeSchema = Schema({
    client_id: String,
    service_id: String,
    grant_id: String
});

ScopeSchema.virtual("client", {
    ref : 'Client',
    localField : 'client_id',
    foreignField : '_id',
    justOne: true
});

ScopeSchema.virtual("service", {
    ref : 'Service',
    localField : 'service_id',
    foreignField : '_id',
    justOne: true
});

ScopeSchema.virtual("grant", {
    ref : 'Grant',
    localField : 'grant_id',
    foreignField : '_id',
    justOne: true
});

export default ScopeSchema;
```

**This is my connectionManager method:**

```
import MongoClient from 'mongoose';
import {ClientModel, GrantModel, ServiceModel, ScopeModel } from '../schemas';

class ConnectionManager {
    constructor() {
        this.mongoClient = MongoClient;
        this.mongoClient.Promise = Promise;
    }
    async connect() {
        await this.mongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {'useMongoClient' : true});
        this.client = this.mongoClient.model('Client', ClientModel);
        this.grant = this.mongoClient.model('Grant', GrantModel);
        this.service = this.mongoClient.model('Service', ServiceModel);
        this.scope = this.mongoClient.model('Scope', ScopeModel);
    }
    getDB () {
        return this.mongoClient;
    }
    getClient()
    {
        return this.client;
    }
    getGrant()
    {
        return this.grant;
    }
    getService()
    {
        return this.service;
    }
    getScope()
    {
        return this.scope;
    }
}
export default new ConnectionManager();
```

Nothing seems to be working with Mongoose so I went as far as trying to update the `client` model:

```
let client = await connectionManager.getClient().findOne({'client' : 'local'});
console.log(client);
client.name = "Hello World";
client.save();
console.log(await connectionManager.getClient().findOne({'client' : 'local'}));
```

The console.log before running `client.name = "Hello World";` is this:

```
{ _id: 5a0706cc26b1572d945811b4,
  name: 'Blah LTD',
  address: '',
  city: '',
  country: 'Unknown',
  telephone: '',
  owner: true,
  url: '',
  client: 'local',
  client_secret: 'secret',
  email: 'email' }
```

The console.log after updating `client.name = "Hello World"; client.save();` is this:

```
{ _id: 5a0706cc26b1572d945811b4,
      name: 'Blah LTD',
      address: '',
      city: '',
      country: 'Unknown',
      telephone: '',
      owner: true,
      url: '',
      client: 'local',
      client_secret: 'secret',
      email: 'email' }
```

As you can see the `client.name` isn't updating to `Hello World`.

Comment: The `Client` model has an "array of scopes" that you are meant to be adding to. Storing the reference to `Client` on the document in the `Scope` model does not automatically update that for you. You need to "push" to the array in `Client` **as well**. Either that or use "virtuals" in the `Client` model, "instead of an array". The latter is demonstrated in the documentation, under [Populate Virtuals](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals). But for your existing schema, add to the `"scopes"` array in `Client` as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn I tried `client.scopes.push(scope)` but, got `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. At this point, I'm uncertain what's happening.

Comment: @NeilLunn I've updated the code above based on your recommendation for virtual however the problem still persist.